# Relating to folder locations when building help project in Winchm

Tags: chm, helpfile

I am using Winchm for building CHM files. I have a question about Winchm and not about html or building help files in general.
More specifically the question relates to directory structure when building a chm file.

If any body reading this has experience with Winchm in particular, then please help me to solve the problem.

I have the following directory structure (which i feel is self-explanatory)

htmlfiles

images

stylesheets

scripts

Wherever applicable my ht
ml files have a reference to the image/stylesheet/script to be used as follows  "../imagefilename.jpg" or "../scriptfilename.js" etc

When i open the project I notice that the html page loads the image okay. Different story when I compile my files. In spite of the relative referencing of the file path the output chm does not use the stylesheet or pick up the image.

However when i move the folders (images, stylesheets & scripts) to the html files folder the output chm works as expected.

The conclusion that I have drawn is that the relative referencing does not work for the compiler and that the three folders should be in the htmlfiles directory (or in the same folder as the html files)

Questions

1. Is the above conclusion correct?
2. If it is not correct, what might be the problem?
3. Is this a generic sort of thing i.e. applicable to all html file building creation tools/ suites? Or is this specific to Winchm?
4. Are there any specific tools that do not require to have the three folders in the same directory as the html files?

In case you have any answers that can help, please let me know

Have a great day!
Romi

Answer (score 0):

I don't know winchm, but use a different dumping tool to extract the CHM back to HTML might reveal how winchm transforms its projects to the CHM internal filesystem.

Maybe it puts the "htmlfiles" in the root of the filesystem.